# Show Procedure error MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Is there an error in this code `SHOW PROCEDURE CODE proc_name`?
The MySQL documentation says it's correct, but I keep receiving a 1064 error anytime I run the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement is a MySQL extension that is available only for servers that have been built with debugging support.

So, obviously your mysql does not have debugging enabled
because error 1064 stand for parse error.

To enable debug in mysql, is quite straightforward :-
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_debug

provide mysql is configured [--with-debug](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/source-configuration-options.html#option_configure_with-debug)

Comment: How do I enable the debugging?

Answer (score 2):

You can get your informations from here:

```
SELECT ROUTINE_DEFINITION FROM information_schema.ROUTINES WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME='proc_name'
```